# Energy distance between random variable and random sample

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent RVs we can expect $\mathbb{E}|X-Y|$ to be a measure of how "far apart" the variables are, but it doesn't work like a metric in the sense that its minimum is positive, attained when $Y=X'$ is an iid RV. But we can actually offset the expectation $\mathbb{E}|X-Y|$ accordingly - that is, if we pick $X'$ and $Y'$ to be iid with $X$ and $Y$ then

$$ d(X,Y)^2=2\mathbb{E}|X-Y|-\mathbb{E}|X-X'|-\mathbb{E}|Y-Y'| $$

which apparently equals

$$ =2\int_{\mathbb{R}} \big(F_X(t)-F_Y(t)\big)^2\,\mathrm{d}t $$

and $d(X,Y)$ is called the **energy distance** which measures how close $X$ and $Y$ are in distribution.

Given a random variable $X$, we can define an energy function $E(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ to be (half the squared) energy distance between $X$ and the discrete uniform distribution on the set $\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}$. Then  given a random sample, i.e. $n$ RVs $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ which are iid with $X$, we can define the energy variable $E=E(X_1,\cdots,X_n)$, which is itself an RV.

**Question**. Do we know anything about how $E$ is distributed? Can we calculate it explicitly, or any nice statistics (like mean, median, etc.) for particular RVs $X$? What about good estimates? Presumably as $n\to\infty$ we have $E\to0$ in some sense, can we describe how fast and in what sense $E$ converges to $0$ (in terms of $X$'s distribution)?

If $U$ is the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ I calculated

$$ E(u_1,\cdots,u_n) = \frac{1}{12n^2}+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(u_k-\frac{2k-1}{2n}\right)^2 $$

where $0<u_1<\cdots<u_n<1$. This tells us $E_{\mathrm{min}}=\frac{1}{12n^2}$ is attained when $u_k=\frac{2k-1}{2n}$, and possibly $E_{\mathrm{max}}$ is attained when $u_k=1$, though it seems too difficult to find $F_E(e)$ for the median, although the mean looks calculable, albeit with a pretty large formula.

---

*Edit*. Intuitively, a point-set being in a narrower range should make $E$ larger, so we should expect $E_\mathrm{min}$ to not occur at a boundary point, so we can find it by solving $\nabla E=0$, which occurs at the vector $\vec\alpha$ for which $F_X(\alpha_k)=\frac{2k-1}{2n}$ for $k=1,\cdots,n$. Then we may integrate $\nabla E$ from $\vec\alpha$ to $\vec x$ to obtain a generalized energy formula:

$$ E-E_{\mathrm{min}}=\frac{2}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \int_{\alpha_k}^{x_k}(x_k-u)f_X(u)\,\mathrm{d}u. $$

Plugging order statistics $X_{(k)}$ into this doesn't seem very amenable but it's a nice formula.

Comment: So, you want to characterize the behavior of the energy distance between the true distribution and the empirical distribution on a sample of size $n$ (rephrasing the question)?

Comment: In particular, if $X$ is non-negative and has a finite expectation, you can write $$\int_\mathbb{R}(F_X(t)-F_{X_n}(t))^2 dt \leq \|F_X-F_{X_n}\|_\infty \cdot 2\mathbb{E}[X]$$ and use standard results on convergence \of the empirical distribution in Kolmogorov distance to bound $\|F_X-F_{X_n}\|_\infty$ as a function of $n$.